# What's a good replacement for a Deore LX 3x10 front derailleur?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front

I recently acquired a Novara Randonee 2014 that came with a Deore LX 44-32-22 crankset, a 10-speed 11-32 cassette, and a Deore LX front derailleur with a stuck and stripped H screw. I broke that screw with a misguided attempt to drill it out. The derailleur still shifts, but poorly. Uphill, when there's tension in the chain, it cannot drop the chain from the middle to the small chainring, nor can it lift the chain from the middle to the large chainring. On level ground it shifts OK. This is with a SRAM TT500 friction bar end shifter. My guess is that even if the H screw broke stuck at the correct limit -- so it does not affect the performance -- this derailleur must probably go because of its other shifting troubles. If I am wrong, I would be grateful for any advice about how to make the derailleur shift properly. And if I am right, what 3x10 front derailleur would do a better job with this crankset and shifter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any Shimano 3x10 MTB Derailleur, but Deore FD-M6000 is a good match for what you have now.

Be careful that you match the clamp band type and that you get the correct down pull / top pull version to match your current one.

Down pull is where the cable rises from the bottom bracket.

https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/deore-m6000/FD-M6000-M.html

Or

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deore-m6000/FD-M6000-H.html